# MVC Route Hide Controller in URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to make a route where the controller name is not displayed in the URL.

I started with this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewTag",
    url: "tag/tagged/{tag}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Tag", action = "Tagged" }
);
```

And controller method:

```
public class TagController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Tagged(string tag)
    {
```

Which works but generates URL: `tag/tagged/money`

I wanted to use the URL: `tagged/money`

I changed the route to remove the controller name:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewTag",
    url: "tagged/{tag}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Tag", action = "Tagged" }
);
```

Which does route correctly when I manually type in the URL: `tagged/money` but, it doesn't generate the correct routes.

```
@Html.ActionLink(tag.Text, "tagged", new { @tag = tag.Text })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink(tag.Text, "tagged", "tag", new { @tag = tag.Text }, null)
```

Both generate the original and wrong URL: `tag/tagged/{tag}`

I thought the route config was used to both parse incoming URL's and generate URL's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Html.RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493103%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method after dropping `tagged` from the route URL:

```
@Html.RouteLink(tag.Text, "ViewTag", new { @tag = tag.Text })
```

Comment: Thanks. I forget about these other routing helpers. UrlHelper.GenerateUrl also works but takes a lot of parameters.

Comment: @David You can also use `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` (which would be  `@Url.RouteUrl` in your view) method.